# Adobe flash: How to determine users CPU characteristics?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, cpu, characteristics

Adobe flash: How to determine users CPU characteristics? (its mhz, its current ocupation) I need to know how fast is users computer now, and I have only 150 ms for it. How to do such thing in actionscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the API exposed from Flash to determine the CPU speed/usage. Maybe you can try to detect the frame rate, or you can use some algorithm to compare the results with some fixed values.

Comment: and how about JS? Can we monitor mhz with JS or silverlight or Unity3d? Any one of tham?

Comment: You're not going to get this stuff with techinologies that run in the browser because the browser is designed to have limited access to the client hostmachine.

Comment: No, not even with java applets

Answer (score 3):

run a sample of the calculation before the main program executes, and guesstimate from this.

randomly resample at sensible intervals throughout and keep a moving average, just incase the first sample was misrepresentative.

afterall, what you actually need is a working speed, and not a theoretical one.
(the theoretical speed might be 3 ghz, but the working speed might be equivallent to 500 mhz if there are lots of other applications running in the background.)

```
var t:Number = getTimer();
var i:int = 0;
while( getTimer() - t < 100 ) i++;
```